# if any of P and Q occurs, then either R occurs or S doesn't occur. If exactly one of R and S always occurs

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

Consider four events P,Q,R, and S such that if any of P and Q occurs, then either R occurs or S doesn't occur. If exactly one of R and S always occurs,which of the following is always true.

(A) R->P

(B) $R->P^c$

(C) $R^c->Q$

(D) $R^c->Q^c$

My approach is from the given conditions we can infer Q is a subset of R. So, answer should be D. Please verify if it is correct

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You are correct. The first condition says that $P\cup Q\subseteq R\cup S^c$, and the second says that $S^c=R$, so $Q\subseteq P\cup Q\subseteq R$, and hence $R^c\subseteq Q^c$.